# check_password always returning false even if the password is correct?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am using Django 1.5. I am a custom User model like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    #identifier = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, db_index=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=90, unique=True, db_index=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    #password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'
```

I have a custom authentication:

```
class AuthBackend:

def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    if '@' in username:
        kwargs = {'email': username}
    else:
        kwargs = {'username': username}
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Even after entering the correct username and password check_password() always returning false so that I can't login. I tried that in terminal too:

```
user.check_password(password)
```

is always returning `False.`

```
#views.py:

def login_backend(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        state = "Username or Password Incorrect!"
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/overview/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('login_backend.html', {'state':state}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('login_backend.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Yeah looks like this: f8566297ee28e8a3096497070b37b91d24c2 in the database.

Comment: Did that: user is returned with user = User.objects.get(**kwargs) returns the username but after I do user.check_password(password) it returns false. Basically it is authenticating against the username but not with the password.

Comment: Okay sure. give me a second.

Comment: please see my updated question. My password is stored in hashlib.sha1 format.

Comment: You forgot to put `if user.is_active:`. Is the user you input is active?

Comment: I tried with all the users. And they are active.

Comment: Works with correct username and but not with the password.

Comment: if the user is inactive it shouldn't have worked with the username too, right?

Comment: Sure, what's your email address? I also tried everything. I think the problem is with the table. The galaxy_user is the table of Galaxy framework: http://wiki.galaxyproject.org/Admin/Get%20Galaxy

Comment: Please check your e-mail.

Comment: What third apps did you install in your project? I got error about no module. I also have suggestion. Create requirements.txt, in that file save all the third apps you have install in your project so that it will be easy to find and install it.

Comment: Here's the problem I encountered, there is no password field. I can't create a user

Comment: that's the reason why your password return to false

Comment: When you sync the first time your project, you need to create a superuser first. I trace your codes and it's incomplete. You just create a abstractuser model but you forgot the other things. You have no function for hashing password, you have to function for create user, and more. That's why you can't login because there are no function handle to pass password in the authenticate parameter.

Refer to this on how to create an extended abtractbaseuser

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Yes, my user model seems to lack certain attribute.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when you create your CustomUser, you save the password in open-way(without hashing). Can you give me your RegistrationForm code?

In my case:

```py
# forms/register.py
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new account.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']
```

Register-handler:

```py
# views.py
def register(request):
    """
    User registration view.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save() # Save your password as a simple String
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'news/register.html', {'form': form})
```

So when you try to login:

```py
if user.check_password(password):
    return user
```

*check_password* always returns False.

---

**Solution**:
To *set password* properly, you should redefine save() method in RegistrationForm:

```py
# forms/register.py
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new account.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(user.password) # set password properly before commit
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**Or** simply change handler:

```py
def register(request):
    """
    User registration view.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(request.POST["password"])
            user.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'news/register.html', {'form': form})
```